# Visual Studio, svn and merging .csproj and .sln files

Tags: visual-studio, svn, merge

Anyone had any success getting SVN to merge Visual Studio project (.csproj) or solution (.sln) files that have been edited by two users? Example

1. User A checks out project
2. User B checks out same project
3. User A adds a file
4. User A commits changes
5. User B adds a file
6. User B commits changes

Seems to me that at step (6), svn, Tortoise, Ankh or whatever should detect a conflict and either merge the two project files automatically or, more likely, prompt User B to resolve the conflict. Currently, we're seeing changes made by User A obliterated when User B checks in, resulting in bad builds, deploys, etc missing features that had been added before the last checkin.

Since the project files are XML, why is this an issue? Am I missing something here? I've searched the archives here and googled to I can't google no more, but haven't come up with a good solution.

Comment: Have you set the mime-type correctly on the files?

Comment: User B's commit should have been rejected because his file was out of date, forcing him to update (and merge--most changes are indeed handled automagically).

Comment: Yeah, at step 6, the svn client should report that the working copy is out of date. Something must be wrong somewhere, because this works for us.

Comment: I've definitely had it happen if users A and B are on separate feature branches, and doing this with adding projects to solutions (as opposed to adding files to projects).  That may be a separate topic, though...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How do you think you trick SVN into performing step #6? It seems you misunderstood what goes wrong. ***SVN will never ever commit from a working copy that's not up to date***, so step #6 won't work without user B previously updating and merging user A's changes. Honestly. Try it.

I guess what happens instead is this:

1. A checks out project.
2. B checks out same project.
3. A adds a file.
4. A commits changes.
5. B adds a file, but forgets to save the project/solution.
6. B tries to commit changes and gets a message he should update first.
7. B updates.
8. B switches back to VS. VS tells him the project/solution changed on disk and asks whether he wants to a) reload from disk and lose his changes b) override the version on disk.
9. B doesn't understand, doesn't try to understand, considers his changes valuable, and picks b), overriding the changes on disk.
10. B still doesn't try to understand and thus does not diff the version he has on disk with the last committed one and thus misses that he overrode A's changes.
11. B Checks in, overriding A's changes.

I've seen this happening once in a while, usually with a user B who does not really understand SVN's (or CVS', FTM) workflow.

So here's a few hints:

***Don't update unless you have saved everything*** ("File"->"Save All"; for me, that's Ctrl+Shift+S). In case you have made that mistake and you're stuck, do override the changes on disk and then *merge the lost changes manually*. (It might also work to update the project/solution file back to version N-1, and then to HEAD again, in order to have SVN perform the merge.)

***Don't commit without checking which files you changed*** and having a quick ***look at the diffs*** to see whether the changes are what you expect.

***Commit early, commit often***. The more developers work on the same code base, the more likely you get conflicts. The longer you change your working copy without updating, the more likely you get conflicts. Since the number of developers usually is out of your hands, the update frequency is the one thing you can use to reduce the probability of conflicts.

Comment: This sounds very familiar. This may be more of a training issue than a tech problem. =/

Answer (score 2):

I second sbi's answer. One possible solution is to always update from within Visual Studio, at least if you use VisualSVN (I'm not sure how AnkhSVN copes with this situation).

VisualSVN will block visual studio during the update operation, and make sure any changed projects are automatically reloaded, so users can not ignore the external changes.

Answer (score 1):

A rather radical but efficient solution is to use a tool to generate those solution files from a meta-definition and then putting only the meta-definition under source control, not Visual Studio project files (which are a nightmare to merge).

In my team we use [MPC](http://www.ociweb.com/products/mpc) to do this. We have:

- a bunch of .mpc files for project descriptions,
- a .mwc file for workspace / solution description,
- a small .cmd to generate Visual Studio files.

Since they are all hand-edited text files, we no longer have problems with Visual Studio mixing up everything.

The drawbacks are an extra-tool and the need to regenerate the solution files when files are added or removed but there are some additional benefits too:

- project configurations are centralized: for instance, changing a compilation flag is done in a single place instead of on a per-project basis,
- this can accomodate multiple build systems (we currently use Visual 2003 and 2005 but this also works with gcc and others).

From my experience, althgough setting up the tool can be a bit painful (but it all depends on the size and complexity of your project), this is clearly worth it.

Note that MPC isn't the only tool for this purpose. Others exist, such as [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to reduce conflicts by ensuring that your project files don't list every individual file inside the project. This will avoid the project file from being changed in first place when a user adds a file.

You're free to use wildcards inside a project file: [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_Wildcards)

Example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="Src\**\*.cs" />
  [...]
</ItemGroup>
```

It is sad that Visual Studio doesn't encourage this kind of project setup and instead opts for listing individual files.

Answer (score 0):

This is very tedious and tiresome so you just have to plow through it. You will sometimes keep the local working copy since it has all of your custom projects added. However, in other cases you will want to merge in all new items from the Base solution so you end up with everything from both solution files. For readability it is best to place all base product additions before customization additions.

Do not worry that the first portion of the GUID is identical for projects, but it is the last portion that will be unique.

Fissh